# Параллельное выполнение в perl

Tags: perl

Есть некий процесс который я хотел бы распараллелить, нагуглил пример с использованием AnyEvent. По факту через асинхронный таймер:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use AnyEvent; 
use 5.016;
use Benchmark; # Для замера выполнения кода 

my $cv = AE::cv;
my @array = 1..10;

my $start_time = Benchmark->new;

sub worker {
    my $cb = shift;

    my $w;$w = AE::timer rand(0.1),0,sub {
        undef $w;
        $cb->();
    };
}

$cv->begin;
for my $cur (@array) {
    $cv->begin;

    worker sub {
        say "Начало процесса $cur";
        foreach(0...1000000) {
        }

        say "Конец процесса $cur";
        $cv->end;
    };

  #foreach(0...1000000) {


  # }
}

$cv->end;
$cv->recv;


my $end_time = Benchmark->new;
my $delta = timediff($end_time, $start_time);
say "\n\nВремя выполнение скрипта:\n" . timestr($delta);
```

сначала вместо цикла foreach(0...1000000) был sleep, посмотрел по времени выполнения с "асинхронностью" и линейно, время было одинаково (нууу... подумал я, может это слип так работает, он засыпает всю программу, это же все таки псевдо параллельность), добавил цикл, результат так же по времени одинаков. Вопрос, где тут параллельность, зачем заниматься самообманом? 
Я так понимаю, перл работает по такому принципу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
по сути как корутина, т.е. общее время выполнение как не крути будет такое же как если бы код выполнялся линейно? 
Кстати через fork тоже время выполнения равно последовательному выполнению

Comment: твой пример абсолютно ... синтетический. попробуй что-то вроде параллельной загрузки страничек http://pragmaticperl.com/issues/21/pragmaticperl-21-%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-anyevent.html

Comment: Это пример асинхронного выполнения кода, асинхронное != параллельное. 
и причем тут загрузка странички, если мне нужно действие в программе распараллелить, по сути нужно некие действия выполнять параллельно для сокращения времени выполнения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если хочется параллельности для использования CPU (а цикл - это именно потребление CPU), то нужны раздельные процессы. (Или треды, но использовать треды я бы категорически не рекомендовал). `sleep` усыпляет процесс, а т.к. процесс у нас один, то и усыпает он весь.

AnyEvent не для этого (равно как и Coro). Они для создания параллельности исполнения, когда основная часть работы процесса - это ожидание ввода-вывода (в основном по сети), а это подавляющее большинство задач в современных web-системах

Comment: кстати через fork тоже время выполнения равно последовательному выполнению

Comment: А если мы распараллеливаем порождая несколько процессов через fork, если у нас отдельный процесс, это не будет то самое параллельное выполнение? (Кстати, в винде fork не создает доч. процесс, пид какой-то минусовой)

Comment: "через fork" - хотелось бы тогда увидеть решение. Про винду сходу не скажу, но AFAIR fork в perl должен работать. Если несколько процессов, то да - это параллельное исполнение.

Comment: Кстати, для AnyEvent есть AnyEvent::Worker - он создаёт отдельный процесс и обрабатывает задачи в нём, синхронизируясь с основным процессом через асинхроннй сокет

Comment: Sorry, что влезаю. Сам Mons! Был впечатлён рассказом про aefor :) ну и всё что вокруг, на YAPC::Russia 2017, спасибо.

Comment: *Кстати, в винде fork не создает доч. процесс* -- под Windows, ЕМНИП, до сих пор форков нет : [раз](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfork.html), [два](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.api.fork).